# Drupal 7: Edit/delete is not working on the custom module

Tags: routes

I am a newbie to drupal. I am working to create a custom module in the name "course". I have read about the list of hooks to create a custom module. So, what's my problem is that i cant able to see the edit form for the module configure but i can do add management and its working fine.
I've used Existing **contact** modules as a reference.

Below are my code:
In **course.module**

```
function course_menu() { 
  $items['admin/structure/course'] = array(
    'title' => 'Academy\'s courses',
    'description' => 'Create a system contact form and set up categories for the form to use.',
    'page callback' => 'course_list',
    'access arguments' => array('administer contact forms'),
    'file' => 'course.admin.inc',
  );
  $items['admin/structure/course/add'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add Courses',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('course_edit_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer contact forms'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION,
    'weight' => 1,
    'file' => 'course.admin.inc',
  );
  $items['admin/structure/course/edit/%course'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit Courses',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('course_edit_form',4),
    'access arguments' => array('administer contact forms'),
    'file' => 'course.admin.inc',
  );

  return $items;
}
```

and in **course.admin.inc**:

```
function course_edit_form($form, &$form_state, array $course = array()) {
  // If this is a new course, add the default values.

  $course += array(
    'name' => '', 
    'course_id' => NULL,
  );

  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Course Name'),
    '#maxlength' => 255,
    '#default_value' => $course['name'],
    '#description' => t("Example: 'Available Course Names'."),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['course_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $course['course_id'],
  );
  $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function course_edit_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  if (empty($form_state['values']['course_id'])) {
        db_insert('courses') // Table name no longer needs {}
        ->fields(array(
          'name' => $form_state['values']['name'],
          'course_url' => $form_state['values']['name']
        ))
        ->execute();
    //drupal_write_record('courses', $form_state['values']);
  }
  else {
     db_insert('courses') // Table name no longer needs {}
        ->fields(array(
          'name' => $form_state['values']['name'],
          'course_url' => $form_state['values']['name']
        ))
        ->condition('course_id', $form_state['values']['course_id'])
        ->execute();
    //drupal_write_record('courses', $form_state['values'], array('course_id'));
  }

  drupal_set_message(t('Course %name has been saved.', array('%name' => $form_state['values']['name'])));
  watchdog('contact', 'Course %name has been saved.', array('%course' => $form_state['values']['name']), WATCHDOG_NOTICE, l(t('Edit'), 'admin/structure/course/edit/' . $form_state['values']['course_id']));
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'admin/structure/course';
}
```

I can't able to find the exact problem, why add is working but not edit & delete? Help me on this.

Below image tells you what exactly i am asking for(Red mark).
[image]

If anything additional needed in this please let me know.

Comment: Are you sure you have flushed menu cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an [Auto-Loader Wildcard](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7#sub_autoload_wildcards) in your menu item definition for `admin/structure/course/edit/%course`. This wildcard defines the prefix for the load function of your module. In your case course_load() will be called which returns a course object from a datasource.

If the function is not found it will fallback in any of your parent menu items. In your case it is `admin/structure/course`.

This could be an example of you load function

```
function course_load($course_id) 
{
    return db_query("SELECT * FROM {course} WHERE course_id = :course_id", array(
        ':course_id' => $course_id
    ))->fetchObject();
}
```

Your `course_edit_form` doesn't receive an array of courses but 1 course object as third argument.

```
function course_edit_form($form, &$form_state, $course)
{
     // $course is here your Course object
```

Comment: Great... it works.